# Nodejs error due to long running SQL Procedure, POST from Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, http

On my site I currently use Angular / NodeJs/ and a SQL database. On the site I make a lot of calls from the site to NodeJs to the database and it works fine. However, when I run a stored procedure that takes a long time to process I get back the following in the console:

POST /job_bbb - - ms - -

From what I have seen on Google this is due to no response being sent back.

Any ideas on how to remedy this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Angular call to my service:**

```
this.teradataService.getBBB(this.id).subscribe(bbbresults => this.bbbresults = bbbresults,
        error => console.log('ERROR!'),
        () => {
 });
```

**Service HTTP POST:**

```js
    getBBB(id): Observable<[BBBResult]> {
  const url = 'http://localhost:3000/job_bbb';
  const data = ({
    id: id
  });
  return this._http.post(url, data)
  .pipe(
    map((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      return <[BBBResult]> res;
    })
  );
}
```

**Nodejs**

```js
router.post('/job_bbb', function (req, res) {
var id = req.body.id;
      var sql = "CALL Stored Proecedure Here;";
      console.log(sql);
      return database.read(sql)
        .then((x) => {
          console.log(x)
          res.send(x);
        })
    });
```

Comment: Does the console.log from your Node.js get printed? If you run the stored proc from your command line (i.e. not from Node) how long does it take to execute?

Comment: The console.log(sql) does get printed, the console.log(x) does not.

It takes about 5 minutes to complete. This same procedure has worked as intended in the past but now that it takes a bit longer I am getting this POST issue.

Comment: If it takes 5 minutes to complete, I'm not surprised it's timing out... Do you mean that the `console.log(x)` is not printed, even after the 5 minutes? Is there nothing you can do to speed up the execution?

Comment: It never returns, I believe I am getting the POST - - ms - - as the POST is never getting a response due to the time out.

The stored procedure is working correctly on the database end, but before it can finish for the response to go through Nodejs thinks it has timed out.

There is no way to speed up execution. I feel like there has to be a way to get it to wait longer, but I am very inexperienced with Nodejs/Angular.

Answer (score 0):

You might try increasing the server timeout for the server response.
If the node server is Express:

```
 server.setTimeout(msecs);
```

Or probably better:

```
router.post('/job_bbb', function (req, res) {
       req.setTimeout(msecs);
       ....
});
```

The default timeout should be 2 minutes.